# Database dump and restore from AWS postgres-9.6.6 database to Google Cloud SQL (also postgres-9.6)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql

I've dumped my database as described in [Exporting data from an externally-managed database server](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting):

```
pg_dump -U [USERNAME] --format=plain --no-owner \
--no-acl  [DATABASE_NAME] \
    | sed -E 's/(DROP|CREATE|COMMENT ON) EXTENSION/-- \1 EXTENSION/g' > [SQL_FILE].sql
```

The database I'm dumping from is running PostgreSQL 9.6.6. Google Cloud SQL also uses 9.6.

Then I have copied the db-dump to a bucket and tried to restore it as [described here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/importing).

That yields this error message from the web interface at cloud.google.com:
[image]

Any idea how I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the pgcrypto extension. The sed post-processing comments out all extension statements in the SQL dump file. You need to un-comments the neccessary and cloud sql supported extensions like pgcrypto and leave only not supported commented. You can find info about supporee extensions at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions.

Comment: That was it. Thanks! :-)